# Display Custom Error Pages on IIS 7.5 and IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I use Asp.net 4 C# and IIS 7 locally and IIS 7.5 on Production Server.

I need display Custom Error Pages. At the moment I use some logic in my Global.asax to bypass IIS default pages.
Locally using IIS 7 I was able to successfully display CustomPages but on production (IIS 7.5) Server defaults IIS pages persists.
I use `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;` but on Production Server does not work.

Could you point me out a solution to this problem?

My code in `Global.Asax`

```
Application_Error

Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
                if (ex is HttpException)
                {
                    if (((HttpException)(ex)).GetHttpCode() == 404)
                    {

                        Server.Transfer("~/ErrorPages/404.aspx");
                    }
                }
                // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs.
                Server.Transfer("~/ErrorPages/Error.aspx");
```

Comment: just out of curiosity why are you not just letting your web.config handle the custom errors? Log in application_error if necessary and let the config handle the next. Easier to turn on /off, configure, etc.

Comment: Adam I do Server Transfert to get a 404. Asp.net Custom Error when displayed show up 302 redirect by defaults

Comment: indeed she does, but why's that an issue specifically for you? to return a real 404 status for google? if its for end clients, caution as flavors of IE (7?) show the built in 'friendly' errors if your content is less than 500 bytes or so. strange behavior so just want to check on the reason behind this.

Answer (score 2):

The way I have done it is in a module rather than the Global.asax and hooked it into the standard custom error stuff. Give this a try:

```
public class PageNotFoundModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose() {}

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.Error += new EventHandler(context_Error);
    }

    private void context_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;

        // Only handle 404 errors
        var error = context.Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;
        if (error.GetHttpCode() == 404)
        {
            //We can still use the web.config custom errors information to decide whether to redirect
            var config = (CustomErrorsSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/customErrors");

            if (config.Mode == CustomErrorsMode.On || (config.Mode == CustomErrorsMode.RemoteOnly && context.Request.Url.Host != "localhost"))
            {
                //Set the response status code
                context.Response.StatusCode = 404;

                //Tell IIS 7 not to hijack the response (see http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/745738.aspx)
                context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

                //Clear the error otherwise it'll get handled as usual
                context.Server.ClearError();

                //Transfer (not redirect) to the 404 error page from the web.config
                if (config.Errors["404"] != null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer(config.Errors["404"].Redirect);
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer(config.DefaultRedirect);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm trying, could you post an example of your Web.Config? Thanks

Comment: <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="PagNotFoundModule" type="Lib.Core.Web.HttpModules.PageNotFoundModule, Lib.Core"/>
</modules>