# custom error pages in IIS for Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-7, custom-error-pages

In windows 7 I'm trying to set up custom error pages. One for 404, one for 500, and one catch all for any other error (client side or server side) that a user may encounter when something times out, or there is a malfunction when asp does its compiling.

```
404.htm
500.htm
error.htm
```

Just really simple html pages that say error and nothing technical like the defaults. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292933/iis-7-0-doesnt-display-custom-error-pages) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727570/display-custom-error-pages-on-iis-7-5-and-iis-7) seem to be talking about crafting the error pages in ASP, not just taking an html file and setting it as a custom error page.

In IIS I have gone to the error page selection tool that is not meant for ASP

[image: IIS Error menu]

And entering this information into the `Edit error pages settings` dialogue

Full address I've entered: WebvView\webview_error_pages\error.htm (by selecting after I've hit the elipses button to the side to browse. (I've shortened all of these addresses for this post).

[image]

The custom default address works. But when I try to make an error page for 404 like this:

[image: dialogue for 404]

[image: 404 appears on list]

and try to go to a page which doesn't exist, I get this simple error message:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
>   occurred.

Not mine. And not the default that was working before I set up the custom 404.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

also, I've just changed some part of the ASP and gotten a runtime error and not my custom error. Is there any way to stop users from seeing these frighteningly technical pages??

**EDIT**
this is the xml code for the other status menus:

```
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
        <customErrors defaultRedirect="webview_error_pages/error.htm" mode="On">
        </customErrors>
  </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
            <remove statusCode="502" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="412" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="406" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="405" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there a specific reason why you're not doing this in your web.config? This will help if you move your project to a different server, you then won't have to worry about manually configuring IIS. Also, it's a bit easier to configure it in web.config IMO.

In the customErrors node under system.web, make sure you have

```
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/" >
           <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404Redirect/"/>
        </customErrors>
```

Obviously you can substitute whatever redirect page you'd like.

Comment: Thanks! where is the location of the file? is that where the tilde is? Will it work for those compilation errors asp is giving me :/

Comment: The tilde character represents the root directory of the application. This will work for compilation errors

Comment: Wow, going to the source really worked. For whatever reason having used IIS to turn that feature to "always" on, did not change the `xml` config file. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: I added the code for the custom error messages. Do you know how I can amend that code to add a 404 page? Thanks.

Comment: I added what I consider to be the relevant code to the last edit on the question :D